# RTSP Return 401 (unauthorised)

Tags: ios, ios10, rtsp

I am trying to fetch cctv video in my `iPhone` App. But I am getting `401 (unauthorised) error`. I read that this error is related to username and the password. But when I inquired with the concerned person he said that the camera do not have any password. Only username has been set. **I have the following link with me to run the video:**

> rtsp://admin@ip:port/videoMain

**Please note**: When I tried running the same in `VLC player` it ran successfully but same when I am accessing through code I am getting `401 error`.

Comment: same problem, there is an auth patch for ffmepg i didn't find yet..

Comment: @pirs sorry for late reply,.. you need to use rtsp://admin:@ip:port/videoMain format. Add : after admin even if password is not there.

Comment: In my case i need to use `Https transport` it didn't work so.. :-(